# C/C++ include path in Android source code

Tags: android, c++, c, dalvik, android-runtime

**Without using compiler or environment variable options**, how to include a reference to the

[dalvik.h](http://androidxref.com/4.3_r2.1/xref/dalvik/vm/Dalvik.h) (/dalvik/vm/Dalvik.h) file

inside the

[Parcel.cpp](http://androidxref.com/4.3_r2.1/xref/frameworks/native/libs/binder/Parcel.cpp) (/frameworks/native/libs/binder/Parcel.cpp) file **in Linux/Ubuntu operating system**?

I tried the following inside the Parcel.cpp file but non of them works:

```
#include "Dalvik.h"
#include "/dalvik/vm/Dalvik.h"
#include "/home/user/android/dalvik/vm/Dalvik.h"
```

Also I am aware of multiple similar questions such as [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8558057/converting-an-absolute-path-in-include-in-c), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12562807/include-absolute-path-syntax-in-c-c/12563042#12563042), and [3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13362060/gcc-generate-absolute-paths-for-includes-in-debug-symbols) but non of them answer my question because they use compiler or environment options or work only for Windows operating system.